# Is there any way to append Other Swift Flags values with shell script?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

I am trying to add Other Swift Flags with shell script
but i can't find a way

The reason why we want to add Other Swift Flags values in the shell is because we are operating the feature-flags dynamically.

Previously, we were passing it as a parameter of build_app on fastlane, but now we're switching CI to xcode-cloud, and for that, we're looking for a way to deliver the flag in ci_script

If there's any way to add it, could you tell me how to do

Comment: Using `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` in `xcodebuild` doesn't work? `xcodebuild ... "SWIFT_FLAGS=-D FLAG"`?

Comment: @Larme xcodebuild would be work but I want to build with xcode-cloud not command build 

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate shell script which runs `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -json`, then use `jq` to parse the output and find the flags you're looking for.